# Disabling a specific VS code analysis rule (IDE0058) globally, without writing to a project-specific file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, roslyn, roslyn-code-analysis

I work frequently in multiple EF Core projects across multiple solutions. It's getting very frustrating seeing [IDE0058 analysis hints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/ide0058) everywhere whenever I'm saving a `DbContext`:

[image: IDE0058 Warning]

From what I can gather, suppressing this code style violation requires modifying at least one file:

- Adding a local discard for every call to `database.SaveChangesAsync` (looks terrible)
- Adding a `System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage` annotation on a per-method basis (again not ideal)
- Adding a `GlobalSuppressions.cs` file to each project in the solution (really not ideal either)
- Adding a `.editorconfig` file to each project to configure this violation. None of the projects I work with use editorconfig files.

For code review reasons, I can't just keep adding irrelevant files/changes like this whenever I work on a different project.

The thing that gets me is that I swear this is a recent issue. I've been working in EF Core for years up until now and this has not been an issue.

Further to this, [a Roslyn team member commented on GitHub saying it has "no UI impact" and "is hidden by default"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/32721#issuecomment-504954855) (clearly not the case here). There appears to be no way of "resetting" this to the default value, as the linked comment suggests, either.

Is there anyway to suppress this violation, once and for all, **across every project and solution that I work on?**

Comment: You don't need an .editorconfig file per project, just one in a common base directory (unless projects do have .editorconfig files with `root = true` in them).

Comment: @jack-greenhill did you ever find a solution to this problem in the manner you describe?  I have been looking for the same and just came across your post here.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can create a global `Analyzers.ruleset` file and add the rule ids you wish to ignore.

In the `.csproj` file of each project, you will have to add in the `PropertyGroup` section the `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` and specify the path to the `ruleset` file.

The `ruleset` file is an `XML` file and this is an example of what you can do:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RuleSet Name="Rules for Core Application" Description="Custom Rules" ToolsVersion="16.0">
  <Rules AnalyzerId="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features" RuleNamespace="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features">
    <Rule Id="IDE0058" Action="None" />
  </Rules>
</RuleSet>
```

This is how the file looks:

[image]

You can decide for each one if it is a warning/message/error/hidden/info/none.

**Update**:

One more way would be to add a `.editorconfig` file and ignore the warning there.

```
dotnet_style_readonly_field = false:none
```

Comment: I'm ideally looking for some global VS-specific setting to configure this; having to modify each project (there are many) specifically is not a solution in my case. Especially since apparently this is not the default behaviour for this CA warning.

Comment: @JackGreenhill This is a global solution. You just need to connect the `csproj` with this file which is a one-line... It will be something like this: `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>Analyzers.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>`

Comment: @JackGreenhill I have one more idea, will update my answer now.

Comment: @JackGreenhill Updated. If you need more info about `.editorconfig` file, let me know and I will add more details.

Comment: Is the .editorconfig rule not this: csharp_style_unused_value_expression_statement_preference = discard_variable:none